# Unable to forward an email due to run-time error '287'

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myitems = myInbox.Items

For Each myitem In myitems
    If myitem.Class = olMail Then
        If InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Greetings") > 0 Then
            senderemail = myitem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            If senderemail = "abc@xyz.com" Then
                Set oMail = myitem.Forward
                oMail.Recipients.Add "i@me.com"
                oMail.HTMLBody = "Hi"
                oMail.Display
            End If
         End If
    End If
Next myitem
```

My code use to run properly a few weeks back. Today I ran again and debugging it I see that once it comes to  **Set oMail = myitem.Forward** I get an outlook window open and an Run-time error saying Application-defined or object-defined error.

How can I get the forward email and error at the same time? First I use to get the outlook window only after the display command. Also due to this I am not able to execute the next lines of code in my forward email.

**Edit:**

Also now I see that directly displaying the email does not give any error, but once I use **.Forward** command this is when error comes.

Comment: what version of Outlook?  there is an option to allow automation in the trust center settings.

Answer (score 0):

Few Errors in your code, so I clean it up and added more code - Try it and let me know.

```
Option Explicit
Sub olForward()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olSender As String

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    '// Require this procedure be called only when a message is selected
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If olItem.class = olMail Then
            If InStr(1, olItem.Subject, "Greetings") > 0 Then
            olSender = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
                If olSender = "abc@xyz.com" Then
                Set olItem = olItem.Forward
                    olItem.Recipients.Add "Om3r <i@me.com>"
                    olItem.HTMLBody = "Hi" + olItem.HTMLBody
                    olItem.Display
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```